# Swift: Cannot invoke 'filter' with an argument list of type '((Any) throws -> Bool)'

Tags: ios, swift, filter, swift3

I have a fetch request that comes back with some data, that I would like to filter, like so:

```
// Set up fetch request 
let finalVariants : [DBVariant]
do {
  let variants = try context.fetch(request)
  finalVariants = variants.filter() { $0.variant == true }
} catch let error as NSError {
  // Handle error 
  finalVariants = []
}
```

Writing this code, Xcode gives me the error in the title:

```
Cannot invoke 'filter' with an argument list of type '((Any) throws -> Bool)'
```

The code in the filter block does not throw, moving the filter block into a separate var with the signature (Any)->Bool did not help.

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be that I wasn't unwrapping and assigning type to the optional result of the fetch request, so the working code looks like:

```
// Set up fetch request 
let finalVariants : [DBVariant]
do {
  let variantsResult = try context.fetch(request)
  if let variants = variantsResult as? [DBVariant] {
    finalVariants = variants.filter() { $0.variant == true }
  } else {
      finalVariants = []
  }
} catch let error as NSError {
  // Handle error 
  finalVariants = []
}
```